# My django project is searching for url patterns in sample Django Project

Tags: django, ubuntu, windows-8, bitnami

I have a django project made on ubuntu. Now i want to deploy it on windows 8. for that I am using Bitnami.

I have performed all steps under "Django application configuration" on this link. 
[Binami Django Stack](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/Bitnami_Django_Stack#How_do_I_start_and_stop_the_servers.3f)

after starting apache server & starting my localhost/Project, I got "first Django-powered page."

I also get the same for my project by going to localhost/myproject. but the problem is that when I am going to 'localhost/myproject/index' to go to my login page in myproject, It is showing following error

---

Using the URLconf defined in Project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^$
The current URL, index/, didn't match any of these

---

I dont know why is it searching for url patterns in Project instead of myproject? have i done any misconfuguration in apache's 'httpd.conf' file??
Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: did you add the conf folder correctly ?

Comment: Yes. I did it exactly as shown on the link specified & cross checked it many times.

Comment: Can you show the urls.py sample ..!